# How can I pass data to my iOS app from a firebase cloud function without making a regular function call request?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase Cloud Function that I call from a URL rather than a function. The URL is used to load a WKWebView and the function is being called using one of the parameters in the URL, specifically the return_url.

An example of the URL to load the WKWebView would be https://domain.name?app_name=app_name&return_url=cloud_function_url.

```
private func loadWKWebView() {
    
    let url = "https://domain.name"
    let params = "param1=param1&return_url=\(cloud_function_url)"
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    
    request.httpBody = params.data(using: .utf8)
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data : Data?, response : URLResponse?, error : Error?) in
        if data != nil {
            if let returnString = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.webView.loadHTMLString(returnString, baseURL: URL(string: url)!)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    task.resume()
    
}
```

The URL loads an authentication page in which the user must enter their username and password and returns the parameter I need.

I can console log the parameter but I don’t know how to pass the data to my iOS application because it is not a function “directly” that is making the call to the function expecting the result. The result depends on whether the user enters a valid username and password.

How can I send the response once the user logs in to my app?

Answer (score 1):

What you are putting in `params` is query parameters. That should be appended to the URL, not sent as data in a POST.

I suggest using a `URLComponents` struct to compose your URL from the parts you need (probably `host` plus `queryItems`.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using POST in order to load the URL in the WKWebView otherwise it will not work with the method shown above. I can see the data in the logs and I'm able to send it. I just do not know how to write a method that would receive the response like I normally would with either a callable or http request function.